# C++ / Linux / GTK UI - Media Player library or object

Tags: c++, media-player, c

I'm struggling to create a media player inside my c++ program. I started studying the references of libvlc and libgstreamer, but both are incomplete and buggy.

Is there some free library I can employ for my task? Or is there some library that provide a ready-to-use object in my program (using gtk ui)?

Comment: libmpv can do that

Answer (score 1):

MFormats from Medialooks is perfect for this but it is not free, the only free one that i know of is FFMpeg but it is not easy to use.

Nigel.

Comment: Nigel, can you add a link and tell us why you think it is perfect?